# How to do TDD using Pex for SharePoint based application

Tags: sharepoint, tdd, pex

I am working on creating an application which is based on SharePoint Foundation 2010. I'm looking for a way to take advantage of the TDD methodology. While reseacrhing for TDD I read about Pex and Moles. Can anyone advice on what is the best approach to implement TDD for a SharePoint based custom solution. Please provide links to relevant articles or videos which can help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use PEX for TDD.  TDD requires you to write a failing test first, then write code to make the test pass.  PEX requires you to write code first, then it generates tests for you.  Something like NUnit is more suitable for TDD on .NET. Sorry, I don't know enough about SharePoint to comment on anything specific that it requires.

Comment: Hi Mike...Thanks for your inputs. Can you link me to someone who has used Pex with SharePoint? There is very limited information about Pex + SharePoint + TDD applied together

Comment: The power of Pex doesn't come from "creating tests after coding", but from "testing theories to find bugs". You can adapt TDD to use this approach. http://taumuon-jabuka.blogspot.com.br/2009/01/theory-driven-development-using_11.html